# Prove the Existence of Modular Multiplicative Inverse Using Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove the Chinese Remainder Theorem using Coq.
currently, I'm trying to prove the existence of modular multiplicative inverse, this is what I've done so far:

```
Theorem modulo_inv : forall m n : Z, rel_prime m n -> exists x : Z, (m * x == 1 [ n ]) .
Proof .
  intros m0 n0 co_prime0 .
  destruct (rel_prime_bezout _ _ co_prime0) as [u v Eq].
  cut (u * m0 = 1 - v * n0); auto with zarith .
  intros Eq0 .
  exists u.
  (* the subgoal is Eq0 *)
  Abort.
```

and all there's left now is one subgoal, which means the same as Eq0 as shown below:

```
1 subgoal
m, n : Z
co_prime : rel_prime m n
m0, n0 : Z
co_prime0 : rel_prime m0 n0
u, v : Z
Eq : u * m0 + v * n0 = 1
Eq0 : u * m0 = 1 - v * n0
______________________________________(1/1)
(m0 * u == 1 [n0])
```

Does anyone know how to show that the subgoal equals to Eq0?

P.S. The definition of Modulo is given below:

```
Definition modulo (a b n : Z) : Prop := (n | (a - b)) .
Notation "( a == b [ n ])" := (modulo a b n) .
```

Comment: Are you already familiar with an informal proof (i.e., not in Coq) of this theorem? Because if you do it is easier to then try to map each step of that proof to a statement in Coq.

Comment: How would you prove the theorem on paper?

Comment: You can also checkout the [proof](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/add6e85884691faef1bf8742e803374815672cc2/mathcomp/ssreflect/div.v#L908) of this theorem in mathcomp library.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I have updated my informal proof, but how do you convert that to formal proof?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thank you, I'll check it out.